# Is the build stage needed in a CI/CD script

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm using this configuration for about two years. I must say I do not have much knowledge about DevOps but I use them to automate the process of testing and aftifact delivery to remote Artifactory.

Yesterday I read an [article](https://testcollab.com/blog/ci-cd-pipelines/) about CI/CD and one thing called my attention, the number 3: "Package first, then run jobs".

One thing I don't like about my pipelines is the time spent... The faster takes 6min, the slower 10-11min.

I'm using GitLab CI/CD and I'm talking about Android App, Android Libraries and Java Libraries.

All of my pipelines has 3 stages:

- `build`, where I run the command **./gradlew assembleRelease**
- `test`, where I run **./gradlew test** followed by a script related to JaCoCo
- `deploy`, here I have several commands to publish the artifactos to a remote Artifactory

I'm starting to think that the first `build` stage could be removed because it does not produce any interesting result (It will generate an artifact in GitLab but I'm not using it). And I'm planning in removing it.

Would that be correct? I'm asking this because it was like somekind of law I've learnt when started using DevOps that every script must have a `build` stage followed by a `test` stage. But if the `test` stage does indeed build it up, then why I build it before?

I'm think about this just as a way to improve the timing of the pipeline. What bothers me is that I need to wait about 10 min to have the artifact in Artifactory to be ready to be used.

In case you ask, in some scripts (the Android ones) I have cache enabled, and in other I don't and I do not see a substancial difference. This is the cache part

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to have any stages that you don't want. In some programming languages you always compile your code, and then it makes sense to use a stage called `build`. The artifacts from this stage could then be sent to jobs in the `test` stage, where the artifacts are used for testing, and if all tests pass, the artifacts could be passed to the deploy stage. For other languages and situations, you can adapt this in any way that you like.

Comment: Thanks @MrBerta! Well about sending artifacts to the next stage, how can I achieve that? Because initially I thought that I was doing that, but after seeing the job's log I realize that it's being built in the `build` stage and also in the `test`. Maybe if I can pass the artifact and the timing improves I can keep the structure

Comment: You use the `artifacts` keyword in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. More info here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts
By default, all artifacts from previous stages will be downloaded to jobs in the next. You can choose which ones you want to download with the `dependencies` keyword:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies

Comment: Thanks @MrBerta! I'll try it and let you know